# How to initialize a countdown timer to reflect the user input

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'm creating a countdown timer based on a users input. When the user pauses and resumes, the timer restarts at the initial inputed value and fails to resume from the current interval. I've uploaded the code into Codepen. 
http://codepen.io/alivera/pen/JGpvRx

```
  //Timer
var myTimer;
var duration = sessionCounter * 60;
var startTimer = function() { 
    minutes = parseInt(duration / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(duration % 60);
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    document.getElementById("clockTimer").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (--duration < 0) {
        document.getElementById("toggleStatus").innerHTML = "<br>Break!";
    }
};

//Start Timer
var go = function() {
    myTimer = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = "Stop";
    document.getElementById('start').className = "btn btn-danger";
    document.getElementById("start").onclick = stop;
};

//Stop Timer
var stop  = function() {
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    document.getElementById('start').innerHTML = "Start";
    document.getElementById('start').className = "btn btn-success";
    document.getElementById("start").onclick = go;
};

duration.onload = stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the time to count down from from the `#clockTimer` element:

```
var sessionCounter = document.getElementById("clockTimer").innerHTML;
```

This is bad because the contents of that element are changing. Often.

And `parseInt` on the next line only is only giving you the number *before* the colon. Your best bet for solving this problem would be storing the current time remaining *and* the previously set time in separate variables, as I have done below.

Your code was a little difficult to work with, so while correcting the error(s), I ended up almost completely rewriting it.

Here's my version; I'll explain it line-by-line (or section-by-section, or whatever):

First, put all of our elements in to easy-to-use (and type) variables:

```
var subBreakButton = document.getElementById("subBreakButton"),
    breakTimer = document.getElementById("breakTimer"),
    addBreakButton = document.getElementById("addBreakButton"),
    subSessionButton = document.getElementById("subSessionButton"),
    sessionTimer = document.getElementById("sessionTimer"),
    addSessionButton = document.getElementById("addSessionButton"),
    breakSession = document.getElementById("breakSession"),
    clockTimer = document.getElementById("clockTimer"),
```

These variables are in **seconds** (thus `m * s`):

```
    breakLength = 5 * 60, // Minutes to seconds
    sessionLength = 25 * 60, // Minutes to seconds
    sessionTimeLeft = sessionLength;
```

Next, a helper method that formats times into a `mm:ss` ... format:

```
function timeString (seconds) {
  var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60) + "",
      seconds = parseInt(seconds % 60) + "";
  if (minutes.length === 1)
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  if (seconds.length === 1)
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Third, event listeners for the plus and minus buttons:

```
// Event Listeners
addBreakButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  breakLength += 1 * 60;
  breakTimer.innerHTML = timeString(breakLength);
});

subBreakButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  breakLength -= 1 * 60;
  if (breakLength < 0)
    breakLength = 0;
  breakTimer.innerHTML = timeString(breakLength);
});

addSessionButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  sessionLength += 1 * 60;
  sessionTimer.innerHTML = timeString(sessionLength);
});

subSessionButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  sessionLength -= 1 * 60;
  if (sessionLength < 0)
    sessionLength = 0;
  sessionTimer.innerHTML = timeString(sessionLength);
});
```

And, the fun part:

```
// Timer
var myTimer;

function startTimer () {
  if (myTimer) // Check to see if a timer was already running, and if so, stop it
    stopTimer();
  sessionTimeLeft = sessionLength;
  myTimer = setInterval(function () {
    sessionTimeLeft--;
    if (sessionTimeLeft <= 0) {
      sessionTimeLeft = 0;
      stopTimer();
    }
    clockTimer.innerHTML = (sessionTimeLeft <= 0? "Break!": timeString(sessionTimeLeft));
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer () {
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = 0;
}
```

Lastly, wrappers:

```
// Start Timer
function go() {
  startTimer();
}

//Pause Timer
function stop() {
  stopTimer();
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQjLZE?editors=1010

Comment: @Harchet Good stuff! Thanks for typing all that out. I solved the original issue but bumped into another problem. I can't get the the timer to initialize to the users input.

Comment: Feel free to ask another question.